# Onclick page should not reload

Tags: javascript

Hi how can i make my page don't reload every time i click another link?

```
function myFunctionD(id) { 
   var x=document.getElementById(id);   
   var myURL = "http:www.sample.php";
   document.location = myURL + "?t_id=" + x.id ;
 return false
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="3" onclick="myFunctionD('3')" target="iframe_a" >July 17, 2013</a>

 <a href="docview.php?id=26" id="4" onclick="myFunctionD('4')" target="iframe_a" >July 18, 2013</a>
```

Comment: try `onclick="return myFunctionD('3')"`, but when you set `document.location` page is reload automatically

Comment: Why are you setting `document.location` if you don't want the page to reload?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the target to open the link in new tab or window . Use `window.open()` instead of `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't even need to use Ajax. You can simply load content of another page in your current page with **Jquery's $.get function**

```
 //Inserting a div for holding another page content. On click of button, this div will update content
 <div id="contentdiv"></div>
 <input type="button" value="Page 1 Load Content" onclick="loadContent('page1.html')"/>
 <input type="button" value="Page 2 Load Content" onclick="loadContent('page2.html')"/>
 <input type="button" value="Page 3 Load Content" onclick="loadContent('page3.html')"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadContent(page)
     {
         //Empty contentdiv for new content and add new page content with jquery's $.get
         $('#contentdiv').empty();
         $.get('http://www.example.com/'+page, function(data) { $("#contentdiv").append(data); });    
         //This will load page content in your contentdiv
         //for more info about $.get visit this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
     }
 </script>
```

In your other pages, just put that content which you want to load into contentdiv. Do not make complete html page with html and body tags etc. Just content you want to appear in you contentdiv.

Comment: it wont change the url when i click the another link

Comment: You want to change the top address bar url on click of button?

Comment: yes, my code was everytime click a link my url was change and if the url was change i want to avoid refreshing of the page. and i dont know what to do?

Comment: This is impossible that you want to change url but prevent page reload. I don't know why you want that but if you want to let your client know where he is currently on which page he is so you can have other option like **breadcrumb** style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ myFunctionD('3'){
            var form = $(this).parent("form");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.attr("yourform"),
                data: form.serialize()
            })

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```